# Can I customize PMD to start automatically after junit test cases failed?

Tags: java, junit

I'm a new programmer in Java and I start using PMD, PMD analysis the code without executing it,but I want it to work with Junit(exactly when the result of the test cases is failed). Can I customize PMD to start automatically after junit test cases failed?

Comment: why don't you run PMD anyway, no matter the code fails or not? The idea is to prevent errors, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.. but my teacher wants that .. He wants to customize PMD to enable it starting only if the result of Junit test case is falied ..

Comment: what are you using? jenkins?

Comment: sorry I don't know what jenkins is.. but I'm using eclipse. do you asking about this?

Comment: because tools such as jenkins are exactly for this kind of thing :-) I think you should give it a try

Comment: OK thank you a lot teacher :-)